# Trying link_to image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I want to turn an image into a link using Rails and have tried this:

```
link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"),
        'http://rubyonrails.org/
```

just like in the tutorial I am following https://www.railstutorial.org/book/
or this after looking in the api doc:

```
link_to(image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), "http://rubyonrails.org/")
```

but it won't work.

> TypeError: Cet objet ne gère pas cette propriété ou cette méthode' which should mean the object doesn't deal with this method

Thanks for the help!

> Same error with image_path (but image_alt works)

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: do you have `rails.png` in your `assets/images` folder ?

Comment: yes I do have the image in the folder

Comment: Those lines are ok, there is no any error, your error raising from other blocks, you need to refactor which block is raising this error, you can this indicate from log

Comment: If I erase all lines from the file (home.html.erb) except this one, I still get the error, so that I don't see from which other block it's coming

Comment: This issue has been solved while working on Bootstrap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928605/stylesheet-link-tag-together-with-bootstrap

Comment: It was probably a problem specific to windows, solved after install of NodeJS

Answer (score 3):

I don't know but maybe the solution after refactoring this way like

**Step 1** Remove these lines from your page like

```
link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"),
        'http://rubyonrails.org/
link_to(image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), "http://rubyonrails.org/")
```

and refresh again your page and see the working without any error? if so next

**Step 2** Show the only image using `image_tag` like

```
<%= image_tag('rails.png', alt: "Rails logo") %>
```

and refresh again web page, the image showing properly without any error? if so next

**Step 3** Apply `link_to` to the `image_tag` like

```
<%= link_to image_tag('rails.png', alt: "Rails logo"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

That's it, if any step is breaking with an error then refactor this step then go ahead.

This working on my hand.

**Edit after comment**

I believing your issue coming for other reason but I don't know what is this reason, I suggesting you go ahead with new course after skipping this issue.

For this issue, you can resolve this using HTML like

```
<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">
    <img src="/assets/rails.png" alt="Rails logo">
</a>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Step 1 is OK. But on step 2, I get same error again. So it comes from the image_tag

Comment: Probably, but rails.png is at the right place and I don't see any problem with the image itself

Comment: Make sure image type ok I mean correct with `jpg`, or `png` or `svg` and try with another image this called refactoring, and image in `assets/images` folder, and restart your server using `ctrl c` see what happening

Comment: Same error happens with any other image, png or jpg

Comment: I will go ahead with `<%= image_alt("rails.png") %>` which works in my configuration. Can't see why `image_tag` is not fine for my Rails setup. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, if  you still facing this then, work with reinstalling rails project, if you think not killing your time, then copy paste old code to new app

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/
```

May be your missing last closing **'**

Add ' in above and try. Or Try below line,

```
link_to image_tag("image_path"), "your_link_here"
```

Comment: This doesn't work... Of course I replaced the image_path with the image as it caused another error.

Comment: The asset "image_path" is not present in the asset pipeline.

Comment: If everything is fine, as per you , then add another image and try. (According to me image name is missmatching)

Comment: Same error happens with any other image, png or jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to your_url do 
  image_tag("image_path")
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.